# Integrate redux form with react tag autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Anyone able to get React Tag Autocomplete work with redux form and have redux form do the management of data?
https://github.com/i-like-robots/react-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in redux-form you can create a custom component and use it into form

In your case, you have to create a custom component for react-tags like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactTags from "react-tag-autocomplete";

const TagAutocomplete = ({ input: { value, onChange } }) => {
  const suggestions = [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Pears" },
    { id: 3, name: "Bananas" },
    { id: 4, name: "Mangos" },
    { id: 5, name: "Lemons" },
    { id: 6, name: "Apricots" }
  ];

  console.log(value);

  const newValue = !value
    ? []
    : value.map(id =>
        suggestions.find(({ id: sugestionId }) => id === sugestionId)
      );

  const handleDelete = i => {
    const tags = [...value];
    tags.splice(i, 1);
    onChange(tags);
  };

  const handleAdd = e => {
    onChange([...value, e.id]);
  };

  return (
    <ReactTags
      tags={newValue}
      suggestions={suggestions}
      handleDelete={handleDelete}
      handleAddition={handleAdd}
    />
  );
};

export default TagAutocomplete;
```

And import into redux form

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

import TagAutocomplete from "./TagAutocomplete";

const SimpleForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>Auto complete</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="autoComplete" component={TagAutocomplete} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "simple" // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm);
```

**Check this codesanbox for live demo https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-simple-example-mg47k**

Comment: Thank you Piyush! I was wondering if it's possible to have input and output to just be an array of IDs instead of array of objects. I know React Tags require {id, name} but the APIs I use only give an array of IDs.

Comment: You can manipulate data on submit, before sending data to api.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking too. Thought it was possible to automate everything inside redux forms without any manipulation

Comment: @Wayne Yes we can, I have updated the code for `TagAutocomplete` component, and also codesandbox demo.

Comment: Awesome looks great! Thank you @Piyush!